# How to pass customized formula to learing_curve_dat of caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression, r-caret, lm

```
train(mpg ~ wt+cyl,
      mtcars,
      method = "lm")

learing_curve_dat(dat=mtcars,
                  outcome="mpg",
                  test_prop = 1/5,
                  method="lm",
                  trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",
                                            number = 3,
                                            repeats = 1))
```

Using train in caret, we can easily customize the formula for lm. How can we pass customized formula to `learing_curve_dat`?

Regarding parameters for `train`, the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-80/topics/learing_curve_dat) explicitly says that "These should not include x, y, formula, or data". How can I work around this constrain? Do I have to create and use my own model to do so?

BTW, why it is called `learing_curve_dat`, not `learning_curve`?

---

Updates:

I found that the `train` in `learing_curve_dat` only support `Default S3 method`, in order to pass formula as an parameter, we need `S3 method for class 'formula'`. I replace the `train` function to be an `S3 method for class 'formula'` in the source code and add `form` as an argument.

```
mod <- train(form=form,
             data=dat[in_mod,,drop=F],
             ...)
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but two comments: (1) Regarding the name: It's a typo in the function name, and has been raised in [issue #278](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/278). (2) Please also note the currently unresolved bug in `learing_curve_dat` as flagged in [issue #866](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/866).

Comment: Thanks for reminding. Seems Max Kuhn is not a big fan of learning curve.